# ems in media query not responding as I change font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts

If I set the font size of the root element to:

```
html, body {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

I would expect the following media query to match on any screen bigger or equal than 1200px

```
@media all and (min-width: 120em) {
     ...
}
```

Instead, 1em inside the media query is still treated as the reference 16px font-size, discarding the settings in the root element

Are ems in media queries not scaling with the font-size set to the root element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An em references the parent element on which it is applied. In other words, if you have a div set to 10px and a p element set to 1em, then the font size for the p element will be 10px if you set your media query for that.

Media queries always reference the browser default font size which is typically 16px.

Comment: the media query was set to match 120ems of screen width. I'd expect that number to match 1200px, considering the changes made to html. Care to explain why it doesn't ?

Comment: Media queries match the browser font size which is typically 16px. You can't change that.